# How to left-justify the workspace of AOSP's Launcher3 like an iPhone

Tags: android

I would like to left-up the Workspace of AOSP's Launcher 3 like an iPhone.
Please tell us exactly what can be done by fixing the source of Launcher 3.

Comment: Why is this tagged google-home?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake